# Where to start to use CRC for error checking?

Tags: iphone, crc

I am trying to use CRC for error checking for downloaded files.
I used NSURLConnection for downloading file.
But I have no idea where to start to use CRC for error checking.
Do I use some libraries? If so, would you recommend me one?
Can anyone tell me where I can find any examples or tutorials for CRC usage in c++ or objective c?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

First off, how is the file CRC handled on the server (if at all)? There are a multitude of algorithms (`CRC32` for simple checksum, MD5/SHA for cryptographic hashes) which can be used, and you must use the same one. If the server does not provide any checksum information (say, from a checksum file), there is no use for a checksum as there is nothing to compare it to.